# Java arrays for a testGrader

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this assignment that cannot for the life of me figure out.  It requires that two files be created, one for input and the other will get data passed into it to perform calculations.

Here is the project description:

> Write a program that grades the written portion of a certain exam. This exam has 20 multiple choice questions. Here are the correct answers:
>
> A, D, C, D, A, B, B, D, A, C, D, C, B, A, B, C, D, A, A, B
>
> To do this you should create a TestGrader class. The class will have an answers array of 20 characters, which will hold the correct test answers. It will have two public member functions that enable user programs to interact with the class: setKey and grade. The setKey function receives a 20-character string holding the correct answers, and copies this information into its answers array. The grade function receives a 20-character array holding the test taker’s answers and compares each of their answers to the correct one. An applicant must correctly answer 15 or more of the 20 questions to pass the exam. After “grading” the exam, the grade function should create and return to the user a string that includes the following information:
>
> - a message indicating whether the applicant passed or failed the exam
> - the total number of correctly answered questions, the total number of  incorrectly answered questions
>
> The client program that creates and uses a TestGrader object should first make a single call to setKey, passing it string containing the 20 correct answers. Once this is done it should allow a test taker’s 20 answers to be entered, store them in a 20-character array, and then call the grade function to grade the exam. The program should loop to allow additional tests to be entered and graded until the user indicates a desire to quit.

---

This is what I have so far, I've spent more time trying to figure out how to do this than I have actually working on it

testGrader:

```
// Chris Brocato
// 04-30-15
// This program will perform the methods for DemoTestGrader

public class TestGrader {

    // Declare variables
    char[] numQuestions = new char[20];


    // Accept and insert answer key into char[]
```

Also if this helps anyone, my teacher gave us this to try and help.
File1: TestGrader:

```
Char[] that is 20 characters longs, should be empty
setKey function that will
     accept answer key
     insert answer key 
         into char[]

Grade function
    Accept student answers
    Compare
```

---

File 2: DemoTestGrader:

```
Main (){
String answerKey = a, b, c, d
Char[] studentAnswers = new char[20]

Ask user for 20 student answers to populate the array
     setKey(?);
     grade(?);
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: I cant wrap my head arround how to get started, due to the fact that i have to pass the answer key into it from another program

Comment: Sorry, but what problem? You have detailed explanation of class. What problems do you have? Can you include what do you try write?

Comment: I am having trouble with declaring the variables so that i will be able to pass the string between the 2 files

Comment: Most likely you will need to read about OOP in Java and read some examples of code. I wrote you basic example for your task. Try to understand it and adapt for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need write base skeleton of your class like this

```
public class TestGrader {
    private char[] key ;
    public TestGrader() { }

    public void setKey(char[] key) {
        // write here in the future saving of your key
    }

    public String grade(char[] key) {
        // write here check answer
    }
}
```

In the MainClass you can write something like this:

```
TestGrader grader = new TestGrader();
grader.setKey(someKey);
System.out.println(grader.grade(someAnswers));
```

Comment: I think you forgot `String grade = grader.grade(someAnswers)` or perhaps just in one line `System.out.println(grader.grade(someAnswes)`  Oh and `public void setKey`...

Comment: It's not necessary. I call method and its String answer send to another method. It's normal practice if I don't need use this result in another places.

Comment: I am just saying the `grade` variable is kinda comming out of thin air right now

Comment: You're right in both moments. I wrote **grader.grade(someAnswes)** but it wasn't save. Correct, thanks.

Comment: no problem, I think this is a suitable answer, it doesn't do the homework for the OP but it does point him in the right direction